# Combine items in a List<T> per predefined order

Tags: c#, logic

My actual use case is more complicated and involves a class, not string but if I can solve the simplified example I should be able to leverage it back. However I can't use a solution that relies on identifying letters or something of that nature.

```
private void Example()
{
    var permutations = new List<List<int>>
    {
        new List<int> { 0, 1, 2 }, // AB + C + D, ABC + D, ABCD
        new List<int> { 0, 2, 1 }, // AB + C + D, AB + CD, ABCD
        new List<int> { 1, 0, 2 }, // A + BC + D, ABC + D, ABCD
        new List<int> { 1, 2, 0 }, // A + BC + D, A + BCD, ABCD
        new List<int> { 2, 0, 1 }, // A + B + CD, AB + CD, ABCD
        new List<int> { 2, 1, 0 }  // A + B + CD, A + BCD, ABCD
    };

    foreach (var permutation in permutations)
    {
        var variables = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
        int count = 0;

        foreach (var i in permutation)
        {
            variables[i - count] = variables[i - count] + variables[i - count + 1];
            variables.RemoveAt(i - count + 1);
            count++;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(variables.Single());
    }
}
```

As shown I am attempting to combine items in a list per a predefined order provided by `permutations`. The provided example works for the first permutation but not the second as the index goes negative.

I have taken some shots in the dark, and while I intrinsically know what operation needs to be done, I can't wrap my head around how to program it.

```
// Fails on { 1, 0, 2}
if (i - count == 0)
    count++;

// Fails on { 1, 0, 2}
if (i - count + 1 < variables.Count)
    count++;
```

Comment: Is there a reason you do the update in place? If you just create another List and copy stuff from the original list, you'll be in much better shape.

Comment: Could you pls explain how `{ 0, 1, 2 }` translates to the combination `AB + C + D, ABC + D, ABCD`

Comment: @AnuViswan Given the simplified example, the list `{ "A", "B", "C", "D" }` goes through three steps for all permutations and all permutations should generate `ABCD` in the final step. For the permutation `{ 0, 1, 2 }` the first step combines `A` and `B`, the second step combines the previously combined `AB` with `C`, the final step combines the previously combined `ABC` with `D`.

Comment: @catbert It doesn't need to be in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things you have to do.

1. index can never be less than 0 or more than the size of the list.
2. increment the count only if `i` is less than the size of the permutation (3).

**Solution**

```
    var answers = new List<string>();

    foreach (var permutation in permutations)
    {
        var original = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
        var variables = original.ToList();
        var perm = new List<string>();
        int count = 0;
        foreach (var i in permutation)
        {
            int index = i - count < 0 ? 0 : i - count;
            variables[index] = variables[index] + variables[index + 1];
            variables.RemoveAt(index + 1);

            if (i < permutation.Count - 1) 
                count++;

            perm.Add(string.Join(" + ", variables));
        }
        answers.Add(string.Join(",", perm));
    }
```

**Output**

answers contain a list of all permutations.

```
answers
Count = 6
    [0]: "AB + C + D,ABC + D,ABCD"
    [1]: "AB + C + D,AB + CD,ABCD"
    [2]: "A + BC + D,ABC + D,ABCD"
    [3]: "A + BC + D,A + BCD,ABCD"
    [4]: "A + B + CD,AB + CD,ABCD"
    [5]: "A + B + CD,A + BCD,ABCD"
```

You can combine and create a single item but this should get you to where you need.